# XML Sitemap not working with Google Search Console..?

Tags: sitemap, google-search-console

I have an XML sitemap located at https://store.usbswiper.com/sitemap_index.xml, which as you can see loads just fine.

However, Google Search Console is telling me it can't fetch the sitemap.

When I use [this validator](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/validate-xml-sitemap.html?op=validate-xml-sitemap&go=1&sitemapurl=https%3A%2F%2Fstore.usbswiper.com%2Fsitemap_index.xml&submit=Validate%20Sitemap) it's giving me a successful validation.

I have checked the [robots.txt](https://store.usbswiper.com/robots.txt), and it's not blocking anything.  It specifices the sitemap URL correctly as well.

Any info on why Google Search Console is giving me this "couldn't fetch" message would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:  When I first ran that validator it gave me this error:

`Incorrect http header content-type: "" (expected: "application/xml")`

I added a robots.txt and then when I ran it and posted this thread it was validating successfully.  I just now tried again and it's failing again with the same message.  I don't understand why it's working sometimes and sometimes not.  The Search Console hasn't successfully loaded at all no matter what the validator is doing.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked there: [Google search console says XML sitemap "can't fetch", yet sitemap passes test and is visible in browser](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/121991/google-search-console-says-xml-sitemap-cant-fetch-yet-sitemap-passes-test-an) but unfortunately has no answers yet.

Answer (score 0):

Add the full link in console;
for example, add `https://example.net/sitemap.xml`
rather than just `sitemap.xml`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).